# Ignore name from Ginger It python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, textblob

im working on text identifying project i use python 3 and libraries

- GingerIt
- NLTK
- TextBlob

I used the below code as a sample

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import nltk
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

blob = TextBlob("my name is john")
data = blob.sentences
a=[]
parser = GingerIt()
for sentence in blob.sentences:
    strVal = str(sentence)
    text = parser.parse(strVal.lstrip())['result'] 
    a.append(text)

fullStrVal =(' '.join(a))
print (fullStrVal)
```

then i can get a output like this

[image]

after i changes blob text sentence to uncommon name it give a error

```
blob = TextBlob("my name is asasasa")
```

[image]

is there any way to skip those words or handle this

Comment: use a `try/except` to handle the exception?

Comment: @davedwards if i use `try/except` then it will ignore whole sentence how can i ignore only that name